# Listagem Lado a lado

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou tentando listar as notícias no wordpress, só que quero listar lado a lado, fiz o **while** padrão do wordpress para listar as notícias `como eu fiz abaixo`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria que as notícias ficassem lado a lado e não repetidas...

Fiz outro teste, retirei a coluna proxima `como eu fiz abaixo`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Funciona da forma que eu quero so que sai do padrão
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você já tentou a função `get_next_post()`? [veja neste link sobre esta função](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php 
  $i = 0;
  while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    if( $i % 2 == 0 ) : 
?>
      //html da coluna da esquerda
<?php 
    else:
?>
      //html da coluna da direita
<?php 
    endif;
    $i++;
  endwhile;
?>
```

Dessa forma vc garante que cada uma vai ser impressa com a respectiva característica de cada coluna.